# Formatting with gg=G on *.cfg files (Nagios) results in bad indentation

Tags: filetype, formatting, autoindent

Search-fu power is eluding me for this one.

Have many Nagios (`*.cfg`) files under audit, using `Vim` to work on them.

Notice that doing `gg=G` is not correctly formatting the files or a block if using `=` with movement commands.

My `.vimrc` looks like this:

```
syntax on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

set t_Co=256

set title
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set shiftround
set smarttab
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set tabstop=2
set smartindent
set copyindent
set autoindent
set mouse=a
set laststatus=2
set number
if v:version > 703
    set relativenumber " Introduced from v7.3 onwards
endif
set ruler
set showcmd
set background=dark
colorscheme elflord

" MultipleSearch
"======================
"let g:MultipleSearchMaxColors = 20
"let g:MultipleSearchColorSequence="darkcyan,gray,LightCyan,LightBlue,LightGreen,blue,green,magenta,cyan,gray,brown"
"let g:MultipleSearchTextColorSequence= "white,DarkRed,black,black,black,white,black,white,red,black,white"

" block cursor (and blinking?) mostly (a fix) for cygwin
let &t_ti.="\e[1 q"
let &t_SI.="\e[5 q"
let &t_EI.="\e[1 q"
let &t_te.="\e[0 q"

" Allow saving of files as sudo when I forgot to start vim using sudo.
cmap w!! w !sudo tee > /dev/null %
```

Thing is, that when formatting a file full of this kind of blocks with `gg=G`:

```
define service{
use                     prod
host_name               some_host
service_description     some_service_desc
servicegroups           some_sgroup
notes_url               https://some.notes.comh/notes.md
check_period            somep_S21h00-S09h00
notification_period     somep_S21h00-S09h00
contact_groups          some_contacsg
notification_options    c,r
check_command           check_nrpe_timeout!30!check_proc2!java!1:1!prod!"important-process"
}
```

Expected:

```
define▪service{¬
▪▪use▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪prod¬
▪▪host_name▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪some_host¬
▪▪service_description▪▪▪▪▪some_service_desc¬
▪▪servicegroups▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪some_sgroup¬
▪▪notes_url▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪https://some.notes.comh/notes.md¬
▪▪check_period▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪somep_S21h00-S09h00¬
▪▪notification_period▪▪▪▪▪somep_S21h00-S09h00¬
▪▪contact_groups▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪some_contacsg¬
▪▪notification_options▪▪▪▪c,r¬
▪▪check_command▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪check_nrpe_timeout!30!check_proc2!java!1:1!prod!"important-process"¬
}¬
```

But, getting instead:

```
define▪service{¬
▪▪use▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪prod¬
▪▪▪▪host_name▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪some_host¬
▪▪▪▪service_description▪▪▪▪▪some_service_desc¬
▪▪▪▪servicegroups▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪some_sgroup¬
▪▪▪▪notes_url▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪https://some.notes.comh/notes.md¬
▪▪▪▪check_period▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪somep_S21h00-S09h00¬
▪▪▪▪notification_period▪▪▪▪▪somep_S21h00-S09h00¬
▪▪▪▪contact_groups▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪some_contacsg¬
▪▪▪▪notification_options▪▪▪▪c,r¬
▪▪▪▪check_command▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪check_nrpe_timeout!30!check_proc2!java!1:1!prod!"important-process"¬
}¬
```

Some settings from the `.vimrc` have been applied locally with no avail.

```
setlocal expandtab smarttab smartindent shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2 tabstop=2 autoindent mouse=a hlsearch incsearch ignorecase
```

Probably, I am missing a basic thing here or is just the *normal* behavior from the `filetype` for `*.cfg` files, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Take a look at [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) and see if that helps narrow things down any further. The interaction of various indent settings can be a bit mystifying at times. I recommend setting very few of them globally and leaving the rest to ftplugins (distributed, plugins, or your own tweaks in `after`). For example, the only one I have globally is `autoindent`, plus `filetype plugin indent on`. I use `after/ftplugin/…` to customize each filetype with `setlocal`

Comment: Vim is trying to indent using C  indenting rules, since there is no indent plugin for plain config files. This will inevitably result in incorrect indentation. Unfortunately I don't have an easy solution for you--you may have to write your own indent plugin. What does the output of "`:set filetype?`" (with the question mark as part of the command) show?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have for example completely disabled the showed ```.vimrc``` config file and trying with only the systems defaults and also with some options in ```setlocal``` mode, still the same bad indentation results.

Comment: @Heptite True that ```=``` uses the ```C-indenting```/```lisp``` way to format things (according to the ```:help =```) but generally this does the job O.K., not this time. To answer your question with/without my ```.vimrc``` I get ```filetype=cfg``` which is fine, changing ```filetype``` won't affect the formatting since it will still use the defaults for ```=```.

Comment: I will go the _hack_ route, either using a ```macro``` or something like [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat), [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) or [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align), but I try to avoid _plugins_ for portability issues, looking maybe to build my own ```indent.vim``` file for this kind of file.